# Angular JS create object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I want to create an object using Angular's factory capabilities. My code is this:

```
angular.module('7minWorkout')
.factory('WorkoutPlan', function(args){
      this.exercises = [];
      this.name = args.name;
      this.title = args.title;
      this.restBetweenExercise = args.restBetweenExercise;
      this.totalWorkoutDuration = function () {
          if (this.exercises.length == 0) return 0;
          var total = 0;
          angular.forEach(this.exercises, function (exercise) {
              total = total + exercise.duration;
          });
          return this.restBetweenExercise * (this.exercises.length - 1) + total;
      }
     return this;
  });
```

I get the following error trying to run this:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: argsProvider <- args <-
>   WorkoutPlan

An ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: what is args? Create a function inside the `factory` and pass your `args` to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that the `args` argument is not a valid injectable module, like `$scope`, or `$http`.

Instead, what you can do is define your class internally and return a new instance of it. Here's an example:

```
angular.module('7minWorkout')
.factory('WorkoutPlan', function() {

  var myWorkoutPlan = function(args) {
    this.exercises = [];
    this.name = args.name;
    this.title = args.title;
    this.restBetweenExercise = args.restBetweenExercise;
    this.totalWorkoutDuration = function() {
      if (this.exercises.length == 0) return 0;
      var total = 0;
      angular.forEach(this.exercises, function(exercise) {
        total = total + exercise.duration;
      });
      return this.restBetweenExercise * (this.exercises.length - 1) + total;
    }
  };

  return {
    create: function(args) {
      return new myWorkoutPlan(args);
    }
  };
});
```

Then wherever you want to use it, you would inject your `WorkoutPlan` factory into the controller or directive, then use `WorkoutPlan.create(actualArgs);` to create an instance

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare to the Angular framework that your factory takes a parameter, like so:

```
angular.module('7minWorkout')
    .factory('WorkoutPlan', ['args', function(args){
        this.exercises = [];
        this.name = args.name;
        this.title = args.title;
        this.restBetweenExercise = args.restBetweenExercise;
        this.totalWorkoutDuration = function () {
            if (this.exercises.length == 0) return 0;
                var total = 0;
                angular.forEach(this.exercises, function (exercise) {
                total = total + exercise.duration;
            });
        return this.restBetweenExercise * (this.exercises.length - 1) + total;
    }
    return this;
}]);
```

Otherwise, Angular will treat `args` as a provider that you're trying to inject into your factory - hence the error. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) (the Factory Recipe section) for more.